# Range() in VBA on structured table stops working when column name has a quotation mark

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

In VBA I have this simple sub-procedure:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim LookInColsSingleEntryArr(0) As Range
  Set LookInColsSingleEntryArr(0) = Range("UsersTbl[Father Countries]")
End Sub
```

I am assigning the data under column titled "Father Countries" in a structured table to a variable. This works fine.

But if I change the column's name to Father's Countries. The command below won't work.

```
  Set LookInColsSingleEntryArr(0) = Range("UsersTbl[Father's Countries]")
```

I get:

> method range of object global failed

I'm guessing I need to escape the single quotation mark. I Tried:

```
Set LookInColsSingleEntryArr(0) = Range("UsersTbl[Father" & Chr(39) & "s Countries]")
```

But I get:

> method range of object global failed

Am I using Chr() incorrectly?

Comment: Use it like this: `Set LookInColsSingleEntryArr(0) = Range("UsersTbl[Father''s Countries]")` Note the doubled single-quote `''`. In a structured reference column reference, you need to use `''` to represent the single quote, even on the worksheet. Refer to it on the worksheet and observe.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld this works! Pls make an answer so I could upvote it. Tks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
Set LookInColsSingleEntryArr(0) = Range("UsersTbl[Father''s Countries]")
```

Note the doubled single-quote `''`

In a structured reference column reference, you need to use `''` to represent the single quote, even on the worksheet. Refer to it on the worksheet and observe.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation essentially says "don't do that".  Use letters, numbers, periods, and underscores.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Comment: Perhaps, but the `Chr(39)` is pointless in this context.  You might make this comment on the original post, rather than my answer.